# Validating multiple forms at once

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-validation

Our app has multiple identical forms on a page. Before submitting the data, I want to validate the inputs of all the forms with a single request from Vue.

I came up with the following frontend portion

```js
await this.axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/data/validate/MixtureFormRequest',
  data: this.forms, // array of forms with identical JSON structure.
});
```

`MixtureFormRequest.php` is just a request class which looks something like this:

```php
class MixtureFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'key1'         => ['required'],
            'key2'         => ['required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Now the tricky part is in the controller:

```php
Route::post('validate/{validationClass}', function (string $validationClass, Request $request) {

    $errors = [];

    foreach($request as $form) {
        $validator = app("App\\Http\\Requests\\" . $validationClass);
        $validationInstance = $validator->make($form, $validator->rules());

        if ($validationInstance->fails()) {
            $errors[] = $validationInstance->errors();
        }
    }

    return response()->jsonSuccess(['errors' => $errors]);
});
```

I have the above, but `$errors` only has a single element. It validates the first form, fails and then sends me errors for that form. I would like errors for each form at once.

Is that possible?

Comment: This isn't entirely clear, and I'm not familiar with the front-end stuff. Are you saying you want to validate the form entries on the server side via Ajax, before the form is submitted? Also I think where you are saying "form" you mean to say "input"?

Comment: @miken32, pretend you have a form on a page. And at the bottom it says 'Add more'. When you click that button, another identical form appears on the page. Now, you send both forms to the backend for validation. And each form will have its own unique validation errors (if any). Does that sorta clear it up?

Comment: Ok I understand. How does your front end send data in such a way that Laravel can work with each form separately? At the very least, by doing `foreach ($request...)` you are iterating over the `Request` object and not the posted data. Using `dump($request->all())` might tell you more about what Laravel sees from the request.

Comment: If you have it so front end sends each form validation separately, it becomes very easy with no server code required at all. Just type hint the FormRequest in the controller method and see if it returns 200 or 422. Otherwise you might need your front end to serialize the forms as JSON and post it that way.

Comment: The frontend is a Vue2 app so I believe it already sends JSON? At least that is how we have our Axios configured. 

But my question is more to do with the actual validating. The forms are getting sent in an array and I would like the errors to be sent back in an array (so I can then show the errors to the users based on the array index).

Comment: As I said, `dump($request->all())` along with fixing your `foreach` loop will likely get you on the right path. I do my front end stuff the old fashioned way, so I have no experience at all with Vue.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work by sending all the forms at once. Instead I created multiple requests like so:

```
        async $validateForms(controller, forms) {
            const formsToValidate = forms.map((form) => {
                return this.$axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: `/data/validate/${controller}`,
                    data: form,
                });
            });

            const results = await Promise.allSettled(formsToValidate);

            return results.map(({ reason, status }) => {
                if (status === 'rejected') {
                    return reason.data.errors;
                } else {
                    return {};
                }
            });
        },
```

On the backend, it becomes quite simple:

```
    Route::post('validate/{validationClass}', function (string $validationClass, Request $request) {
        app("App\\Http\\Requests\\" . $validationClass);
        return response()->jsonSuccess([]);
    });
```

This allows the frontend to control which validation class to use for that particular request.

Comment: So the validation is performed as soon as `app()` is called and it will still return a failure response automatically? That's helpful